# Is paraphilia a disorder?

Tags: sexuality, clinical-psychology

There has been some confusion in recent questions about the term paraphilia. In most questions and answers, including my own, paraphilias have been seen as disorders that might require treatment.

But are paraphilias disorders?

Answer (score 9):

The DSM-5 does not list all paraphilia as a disorder! According to the DSM-5,

> The term **paraphilia** denotes any intense and persistent sexual interest other than sexual interest in genital stimulationor preparatory fondling with phenotypically normal, physically mature, consenting human partners.

What the DSM-5 does list are paraphilic disorders:

> A **paraphilic disorder** is a paraphilia that is currently causing distress or impairment to the individual or a paraphilia whose satisfaction has entailed personal harm, or risk of harm, to others. A paraphilia is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for having a paraphilic disorder, and a paraphilia b itself does not necessarily justify or require clinical intervention.
>
> In the diagnostic criteria set for each of the listed paraphilic disorders, Criterion A specifies the qualitative nature of the paraphilia (e.g., an erotic focus on children or on exposing the genitals to strangers), and Criterion B specifies the negative consequences of the paraphilia (e.g. distress, impairment, or harm to others). In keeping with the distinction between paraphilias and paraphilic disorders, the term *diagnosis* should be reserved for individuals who meet both Criteria A and B.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful reference. I hope you  are linking to it from the relevant question.